# MonoTouch.Dialog: Using different font within the same StringElement

Tags: ios, fonts, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Is it possible to assign different font to text that is associated with a single `StringElement` in MonoTouch.Dialog, e.g. **Reminder**: Doctor's appointment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Jason said you can always create your own `Element`. In fact I generally do that anyway even when my customization needs are minimal. You can have a look at [`MessageElement`](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements/MessageElement.cs) to see how this can be done to render different strings.

You can also opt for a simpler approach using [`UIViewElement`](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs#L1845) and define your `UIView` to have two labels with different font or take complete control with [`OwnerDrawElement`](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements/OwnerDrawnElement.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Look at StyledStringElement instead.  Although I'm not sure that it allows you to mix styles within a single element.  You may need to create a custom element for that.